# How to get EF to recognize a SQL Server column as Computed?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, timestamp

I am using Database first.

I wish to create a column, that stores the `LastModified` datetime of the record. This column should default to `GetUTCDate()`, and when the row is modified, set to `GetUTCDate()`.

I can do the latter using a trigger on the table.

However, when using Entity Framework to insert a record, by default it sends a 0 date in the `LastModified` column, and subsequently the default constraint on the column is ignored and the value is set to 0.

I can manually change the StoreGeneratedPattern property of the column in the .edmx file. However I would like Entity Framework to automatically do this - if this goes live, then I'm relying on memory for it to work.

Is there any way to configure the column in SQL Server such that Entity framework will never send a value when Inserting a record (I believe this can be achieved using a computed column)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EDMX` is just an `XML` file. You can create some simple console application say `EDMXFixer.exe` that you can run on build event and edit your file. We have some common column `CreatedDate` in all tables with the default value of `getdate()`. So I am just editing `EDMX` file and make all those columns as `StoreGeneratedPattern = Computed`.

Then I have this in my pre-build event:

```
"$(ProjectDir)EDMXFixer.exe" "$(ProjectDir)DatabaseObjects\test.edmx"
```

Code for fixer looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i;
    int count;

    XmlAttribute xmlAttribute;

    if ((args == null ? false : (int)args.Length != 0))
    {
        string str = args[0];
        bool flag = false;

        if (File.Exists(str))
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(str);
            if ((fileInfo.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
            {
                fileInfo.Attributes = (FileAttributes)(Convert.ToInt32(fileInfo.Attributes) - Convert.ToInt32(FileAttributes.ReadOnly));
                flag = true;
            }

            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.Load(str);

            if (xmlDocument.DocumentElement != null)
            {
                count = xmlDocument.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes.Count;
                for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    if (xmlDocument.DocumentElement != null)
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode childNode in xmlDocument.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes)
                        {
                            if ((childNode.Name != "Property" ? false : childNode.Attributes != null))
                            {
                                if ((childNode.Attributes["Name"].Value != "CreatedDate" ? false : childNode.Attributes["Type"].Value == "datetime"))
                                {
                                    xmlAttribute = xmlDocument.CreateAttribute("StoreGeneratedPattern");
                                    xmlAttribute.Value = "Computed";
                                    childNode.Attributes.Append(xmlAttribute);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (xmlDocument.DocumentElement != null)
            {
                count = xmlDocument.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[3].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes.Count;
                for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    if (xmlDocument.DocumentElement != null)
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode xmlNodes in xmlDocument.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[3].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes)
                        {
                            if ((xmlNodes.Name != "Property" ? false : xmlNodes.Attributes != null))
                            {
                                if ((xmlNodes.Attributes["Name"].Value != "CreatedDate" ? false : xmlNodes.Attributes["Type"].Value == "DateTime"))
                                {
                                    xmlAttribute = xmlDocument.CreateAttribute("annotation", "StoreGeneratedPattern", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation");
                                    xmlAttribute.Value = "Computed";
                                    xmlNodes.Attributes.Append(xmlAttribute);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            xmlDocument.Save(str);
            if (flag)
            {
                fileInfo.Attributes = (FileAttributes)(Convert.ToInt32(fileInfo.Attributes) + Convert.ToInt32(FileAttributes.ReadOnly));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You just have to change this slightly for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

DATABASE FIRST CASE: A computed column is a read only data, you have to know that you cant write in this column, in the same way as you have to know what data to write in each column of your database.

CODE FIRST CASE:
here an aexample of computed column in an code first object
plese note the annotation `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed`

```
public class UserProfile
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }

     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
     public string FullName { get; private set; }
}
```

The DatabaseGenerated attribute is needed on FullName property. This is a hint to let Entity Framework Code First know that the database will be computing this property for us.

Comment: OP has database first model.

Comment: If you update your `EDMX` from database you are loosing everything and have to make those changes again.